# I need to append the value of free_text_55 to an input box with the same id but first value in first second in second with same id of input box

Tags: javascript, php

Fetched data in form of array.

e.g

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [free_text_55] => free text to add on product 11111.
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [free_text_55] => free text to add on product 222222222.
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [free_text_55] => free text to add on product 3333333333333.
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [free_text_55] => free text to add on product 4444444444444444.
        )
)
```

I need to append the value of `free_text_55` to an input box with the same id. I count the array and start a loop. but it only inserts the first value into input box.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('free_text55').value ='".$advert_edit_form_data[0][$j]['free_text_55']."';</script>";
```

Comment: Your question title implies that you have two (or more) elements sharing an `id`. This is invalid HTML if so.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think he just wants to concatenate them all in one ID.

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes, thanks! i already recognized it and deleted my comment ;-)

Comment: by using .innerText not getting data for 1st on input box also, and agin by using .value getting value for first on. Thanks

Comment: its like generating the input box of same id from database based and then fetching the data for that multiple input box.. but only able to append for first one.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar The problem is you're not appending, you're overwriting. You need to use `+=` to concatenate.

Comment: ok thanks let me try, I am new to javascript :P :)

Comment: I don't want to concante in one id i need first array value in first input box second in second ibput box and so on but all input box have same id.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate all the values in PHP, then store that in the input box:

```
$free_text55 = ''
foreach ($advert_edit_form_data[0] AS $a) {
    $free_text55 .= $a['free_text_55'];
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('free_text55').value =".json_encode($free_text55.";</script>";
```

It's best to use `json_encode()` when converting PHP variables to Javascript, in case there are special characters that need to be encoded.

Comment: Just here to help: the first line might need a semicolon, and the json_encode function is missing a parenthesis

Comment: <?php
    $free_text55 = '';
foreach ($advert_edit_form_data[0] as $a) {
    $free_text55 = $a['free_text_55'];
}
    $li = count($advert_edit_form_data[0]);
    for ($j = 0; $j < $li; $j++){ 
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('free_text55').value =".json_encode($free_text55).";</script>";
     } ?>

Comment: not getting actual value,  getting for first one again same it is.

Comment: Why don't you use what I wrote in my answer? You need to use `.=` in PHP to append to the string.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `$var = value` and `$var .= value`?

Comment: can you please tell me where to add I am really confused. please please I am gratefull to you. thanks

Comment: Instead of copying code haphazardly, try to understand how it works. That's how you become a programmer. Coding by copying is like painting by numbers -- you're not a real artist if you do that.

Comment: Ok thanks for your kind suggestion will keep in mind trying to find out with ur given solution if not will come again thanks thanks a lot.

Comment: Getting the value in concante form my requirement.. if there is 2 input box with same id then array first value in first input box and second one in second input box.. please help me out its urgent thanks....

Comment: You shouldn't have two boxes with the same ID. `document.getElementById` will only return the first one. If you want to have multiple elements that you operate on as a group, you should use classes. Then you use `getElementsByClassName`, and write a loop to process all of them.